# How to do a geo-spital query on Firebase realtime database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I have a coordinate stored in my MySQL database, and I have other multiple coordinates updating in the Firebase Realtime Database.

How can I find nearby coordinates from Firebase real-time database? Does Firebase Realtime Database allow GEO queries?

My Realtime Database structure is attached below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I find nearby coordinates from the Firebase Realtime database?

You definitely need to perform geo queries in order to get locations within a custom radius.

> Does Firebase Realtime Database allow GEO queries?

No, it doesn't. To be able to achieve that,  you have to use a library called [GeoQuery](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/geofire-android/).

If you consider at some point in time try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), then you can check the official documentation regarding [geo queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries). Are really well documented.

Comment: The only reason why I don't want to use Cloud Firestore is it's not real-time. Is there any code to perform a geo query on a real-time database using GeoQuery?

It also seems like this library is exclusive to Android but not universal. For example, iPhone or web

Comment: You can use [real-time location queries with Firestore](https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-Android). Give it a try and tell me if it works.